# Windows Meshing/UV Mapper program?

Tags: windows, 3d-modeling

What are the best meshing and uv mapper programs out there?
Are there good free ones? If not, cheap once? (I prefer, not necessarily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a (very) good one is '[blender](http://www.blender.org/)', check out the feature page:

http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/features/

Comment: Great! Thanks! And it supports so much O/S! Nearly every single one!